# is middleware with business rule wrong?

Tags: middleware, clean-architecture

Controlling which type of user can access each route using middleware (in the controller layer) is not breaking what the clean architecture recommends?
For example:
"Only administrators can use the route to list all users", this is a business rule, it should be in the use-case layer, not the controller layer.

Answer (score 2):

I found a answer here:
"Security is an application specific concern, it belongs to the interactors.  The controllers would access the current user's credentials and pass that information to the interactors.  The interactors would use an authorization service to ensure that their particular interaction was authorized.  The business objects wouldn't know anything about it."

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clean-code-discussion/wHzmboOEHzo